# Modificar posicion de imagen con css

Tags: html, css

Si alguien me puede ayudar tengo una pagina.html con una imagen dentro de un div
el div es `class="avatar"`.
En el css tengo

```
.avatar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 13%;
    width: 65px;
    border-radius: 50px 50% 50% 50%;
    height: 65px;
    background: #448ed3 ;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
}
.avatar img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 30%;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    display: block;
}
```

Esto me da como resultado que la imagen quede en un circulo, pero el problema es que la imagen se me corta en la parte de abajo. En otras palabras no muestra la imagen entera en la parte de abajo.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me muestre la imagen entera o poder mover hacia arriba un poco la imagen dentro del circulo?

PD: el tamaño de la imagen es 
anchura: 687px
altura: 798 px

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código HTML? Puede ser que tengas algo mal ahí.

Answer (score 1):

Si el tamaño de la imagen es siempre fijo, agrega atributos `top` y `left` en tu `.avatar img` con valores **negativos**

EDITO

Agrego ejemplo:

```
.avatar img {
    position: relative;
    top: -15px; /* ajustar los valores para mover la imagen */
    left: -5px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 30%;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner algún ejemplo de lo que describes?

Comment: con el top y lef solo me movio el circulo de lugar no la foto dentro de el :/

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a hacerlo así, te corrijo algunas cosas, aunque seria mejor poner la imagen de fondo, tendrías mas control y mas facil:

```
.avatar {
margin: 13%;
width: 65px;
border-radius:  50%;
height: 65px;
background: #448ed3 ;
position: relative;
border:2px solid #fff;
bottom: 50px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.avatar img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.avatar {

}

.avatar .img {
    width: 150px; 
    height: 150px;  
    border-radius: 50%; 
    margin: 30% auto;   
    border:2px solid #fff;
    background-color: blue; 
    display: block;  
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Por cierto, ¿por qué el contenido de `.avatar` está vacío?